# vlookup in pandas between 2 dataframes to create third dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am wanting to use the equivalent to excel’s vlookup for a new dataframe.  I have 2 dataframes and am trying to v-lookup `df1.Column A value` against `df2.Column A and B` and getting `Value A`.

And the cell beside that is `df1.Column A` value against `df2.Column A and B` and getting `value B`.

Data looks like-

The data is in Columns A and B respectively for both data frames 1 and 2

```
Current ouput                                                                  
    Data frame 1              Dataframe2     

      AC1     AC2               AC10                 AC20                                
    Bus        5              car                      1                                    
    car        3              helicopter               7                                  
    Walking    2              running                  5
```

Desired/Expected output

```
           Dataframe [Neu]    

NaNa                       NaNa    
Car                           1     
NaNa                       NaNa
```

I have tried:

```
dfz = df1.insert(2, '2A2', df1['AC1'].map(df2.set_index('AC1')['2A2']))
print (dfz)

result = left.join(right, on=['AC2', 'AC1], how='inner')
#left.join(right, lsuffix='_l', rsuffix='_r')

#df1.join(df1.set_index('AC2')['AC1'], on='AC2')
```

I have had some success with:

```
df8 = df1['AC3'] = df1.AC1.map(df2.AC10)
print (df8)


df8 = df1['AC4'] = df1.AC1.map(df2.AC20)
print (df8)
```

The exact output is NaN so it's not correct.

Example:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Desktop/zav.xlsx')

df2 = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Desktop/zav2.xlsx')

#df3 = pd.merge(df, df2)
df3 = df1.join(df2)
print (df3)


todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
index = pd.date_range(todays_date-datetime.timedelta(10), periods=10, freq='D')

df5 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(5, 5)),
                 columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
print(df5)


df8 = df1['AC3'] = df1.AC1.map(df2.AC10)
print (df8)


df8 = df1['AC3'] = df1.AC1.map(df2.AC20)
print (df8)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @andrew_reece I included my desired/expected output in the question but you had to scroll to the right a lot.  I will update it.  Thanks

Comment: Did you try instead a `merge` with `how='left'`? Also, is this normal the case difference for car and Car?

Comment: @angelwally That's a typo.  I tried dfza = df1['AC3']=df1.AC1.map(df2.AC10)
print(dfza) .  Same issue seems to be present

Comment: I've never used map before but looking at the docs, I guess you should set the index to the arguments of your function. In your case, df2 should have AC10 as index if you want to merge it on df1.AC1.

Comment: @angelwally Can you show example I am not sure I understand completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the following code working with `map`:

```
import pandas as pd    

df1 = pd.DataFrame([["Bus",5],["car",3],["Walking",2]],columns=["AC1","AC2"])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([["car",1],["helicopter",7],["running", 5]],columns=["AC10","AC20"])

df2 = df2.groupby("AC10").first()

df3= df1.join(df2,on="AC1",how="left").drop("AC2",axis=1)
```

It will output the following:

```
       AC1  AC20
0      Bus   NaN
1      car   1.0
2  Walking   NaN
```

Comment: Is there a way to adjust that for - df1 = pd.Series(["AC2"],index=["AC1"])

df2 = pd.Series(["AC20"],index=["AC10"])   I have about 100 cells of data and doing it that way might take a while.  e.g pd.Series([usecols=1],index=[cols=2])

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you are trying to do here. Could you upload somewhere your excel, with the vlookup to see what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Sure.  I've uploaded an Excel equivalent of what I am after https://dropfile.to/OKBgRVd

Comment: Based on your file, I would do first `df2 = df2.groupby("col1").first()` to take the first entry of df2. Then, `df3= df1.join(df2,on="col1",how="left")`. You can drop the original second column if you don't need it. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Nearly works.  print (df2.columns.tolist())
dfzaa = df1.groupby("AC1").first()
df3= df2.join(df1,on="AC20",how="left")
print(df3).  Hmmz...